# PromptChoice in bot framework displays 'too many attempts' exception

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

I need to prompt user to make a choice and keep the chosen value in a variable and use it at the end of conversation session.

```
var dialog = new PromptDialog.PromptChoice<string>(
    new string[] {"A new request", "Current Request" }, 
       "Which one would you like?", 
       "Sorry, that wans't a valid option", 1);
context.Call(dialog, ChoiceReceivedAsync);
context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);       
}

private async Task ChoiceReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{  
   context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync1); 
   return;
}
```

The above code displays choices but gives too manyattempts exception. Also I used the below code in MessageReceivedAsync1

```
var UserChose = await result;
```

but still result does not store the value.

Comment: Questions seeking book/tutorial recommendations are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I'd recommend you read the [help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);` line that you have after the `context.Call`

`context.Call` is launching a new dialog (`PromptChoice`) and so you cannot do both (launch a new dialog and wait in the current dialog)

Comment: I have removed the option PromptChoice , instead i just wrote PromptDialog.Choice and did not 'call', the code is workable but still getting 'tooManyattempts' message.

Comment: That's exactly the same of doing the context.Call (behind the scenes is doing that). Remove the context.Wait call from the method that is calling to Choice